# Conditionally install file based on a property in wix

Tags: wix

I want to install a file only if a property is set to "yes". Is this the correct way to do it?

The property is ExcelInstalled and is set to "yes" or "no".

```
  <Directory Id="XlStartFolderId" Name="[XLSTART]">
    <Component Id="ExcelMacro_xla" Guid="26D21093-B617-4fb8-A5E7-016493D46055" DiskId="1">
      <Condition>ExcelInstalled="yes"</Condition>
      <File Id="ExcelXLA" Name="AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam" ShortName="XLMacro.xla" Source="$(var.srcFolder)\AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam"/>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - it goes inside the File node:

```
<Directory Id="XlStartFolderId" Name="[XLSTART]">
    <Component Id="ExcelMacro_xla" Guid="26D21093-B617-4fb8-A5E7-016493D46055" DiskId="1">
      <File Id="ExcelXLA" Name="AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam" ShortName="XLMacro.xla" Source="$(var.srcFolder)\AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam">ExcelInstalled="yes"</File>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```